# Apollo server: Get function that will resolve a query/mutaiton in reuqestContext?

Tags: apollo-server

I'm trying to implement at plugin to my Apollo node.js server, where I would like to do something with the resolver function that Graphql will execute. So my question is; can I get the resolver function Apollo will call?

I have tried using the [plugins documenation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/#didresolveoperation), and specifaclly the `didResolveOperation` event. But I can't find the resolver function, or the name of the function. Where would I get this?

```js
return {
  requestDidStart(requestContext) {
    return {
      didResolveOperation(context) {
        // The event fires fine, but I can't find the resolver/mutation that will be called in here?
      },          
    };
  },
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: any solution for this??